# Modeler - output of first algorithm not going to second one and so on

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, lastools

I've a model with subsequent steps of LAStools algorithms. Individually they work well, but in the modeler I get only the first output, and no more. It seems like the second algorithm is not taking the output of the previous one.
The log doesn't show any errors. I've only seen that in input (of second step) it shows `" "` something empty (maybe is here the problem...).

The source is a .laz file, and also the subsequent.
I disabled step 3 and beyond to simplify.

[image: model]

[image: config]